# How to Compare better Memory utilization between two machines

Tags: linux, memory, kvm-virtualization, benchmark

i am having two kvm hosts with same h/w and os,only difference is one host is tuned to use huge pages.

How can i compare which is performing better

I am planning to use some application that is more memory bound and compare its performance for a particular time.

Is there any memory usage simulator that serves similar function,i dont think stress can work in this way.can any one suggest a better way of comparing this?

Comment: what kind of application are you going to execute on these kvm machines?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](http://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Comment: @AndreadePalo Mysql,is there a better m/y bound application that can be benchmarked to compare.

Comment: @MichaelHampton i dont think as duplicate,i asked for a tool to benchmark :)

Comment: @kevin You aren't describing "better" in a quantifiable way. Do that, then proceed per the capacity planning question in terms of how to benchmark. (The tools you want to use depend on what you want to measure -- you wouldn't measure liquid volume with a ruler, just like you wouldn't measure page load speed with `top`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're concerned about how fast your application runs you should benchmark it by running your application. It's unlikely that anything else will replicate your application's behaviour exactly and so isn't a guarantee that your application will perform better. Devise a reproducible task for your application and time it.

Answer (score 0):

What about a combination of [sysbench](http://sysbench.sourceforge.net/) and [vmstat](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/vmstat8.html)?